# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex() > toIndex() on Custom Search

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have modified liferay's default `Blog portlet via EXT` to meet up my requirement.

In `control panel` when I click on `Blogs portlet` and try to search for a Blog with say "test" then I can see the list of Blogs with proper pagination.

For example , for 44 entries of corresponding Blogs I can see 3 pages i.e 3 links:

> 1 2 Next

But when I follow same step for `my customized Blog portlet` then for same results I can see 4 links:

> 1 2 3 Next

Now when I click on 3, empty display appears with backend error saying :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(60) > toIndex(44)

This issue may be related to [Liferay Issue: 25143](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-25143) and also they have marked it as closed but couldn't find what exact modification they have done.

In search.jsp of liferay's default blog

> (html/portlet/blogs/search.jsp)

and my custom blog

> (ext-web/docroot/html/portlet/mycustomblogs/search.jsp)

, I put a log printing total no. of records:

> Hits results = indexer.search(searchContext);
>
> int total = results.getLength();
>
> _log.info("total: "+total);

I observed different out put i.e count was different for both. I am wondering that it might be related to Indexer.

I may need more configuration related between Indexer and my customblog. As of now I have following entry in my liferay-portlet-ext.xml related to search as same as Liferay's Blog.

```
<indexer-class>com.liferay.portlet.blogs.util.BlogsIndexer</indexer-class>
<open-search-class>com.liferay.portlet.blogs.util.BlogsOpenSearchImpl</open-search-class>
```

Can anybody help me to find the exact cause, please.

Thanks

Comment: What have you changed?